# Filtering With EF 6

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a method that is returning an IEnumerable of Materials

```
  public IEnumerable<Materials> ListMyMaterials(int organization)
```

I want to filter it in the controller to only return Materials that are found in a Product that is made by the organization id passed in.

Here is my query:

```
 return db.Materials.
         Include("Organization").
         Include("ProductMaterial.Product.Organization").
         .Where(o => o.ProductMaterial.Select(p => p.Product.Organization.ID == organization)).AsQueryable();
```

The two errors I am recieving are:

1) Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'bool'
2) Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<{}.Models.Materials,int,bool>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

I dont have any problems filtering like this if the property had been on Materials, but I only want materials that are found in a products the Organization owns.

What is the proper way to filter the returned data set using a property found in related objects?

Comment: Have you tried using `Contains` instead of `Select`? It should return a boolean.

Comment: Contains did clear up the first error.  Thanks.   However, I am still not sure what to do about #2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing a complex `Include` in your above Lambda expression you can write a simple LINQ query to result as::

```
(from mat in db.Materials
         join org in db.Organization on mat.OrganizationID equals org.ID
         where mat.OrganazationID=organization
         select new Material{
         ID=mat.ID,
         OrganizationID=mat.OrganizationID
         })
```

I dont have any information of table schema that's why in my above LINQ query I have done join by considering `OrganizationID` as a joining Key.

Here your return Type will be `IQueryable<Material>`

Comment: what is the return type of this query?  I want to return it as a AsQueryable.

Answer (score 0):

It is because this expression:

```
.Where(o => o.ProductMaterial.Select(p => p.Product.Organization.ID == organization))
```

Does not evaluate to true or false. That select statement is a subquery and not a boolean condition